# How to get array into jQuery plugin property object/array

Tags: jquery, arrays, plugins

Probably easy question, I've just never done this before... I'm trying to figure out how you would populate a jQuery plugin property object/array or whatever you call it... with a normal array.

```
var imageArray = new Array();
imageArray = ['images/1000x800.png','images/495x880.png','images/600x800.png'];
```

So, I trying to get that into... the plugin property "image" with an unknown amount of images...

```
jQuery(function($){
  $.myPlugin({
    slides : [
      {image : 'images/1000x800.png'},
      {image : 'images/495x880.png'},
      {image : 'images/600x800.png'},
      //...etc...
    ]
  });
});
```

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do... although I don't know the correct syntax...

```
jQuery(function($){
  $.myPlugin({
    slides : [ for(var i=0; i<imageArray.length; i++) {
                image = imageArray[i];
               }
    ]
  });
});
```

Any help appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `$.map`:

```
var imageArray = ['images/1000x800.png','images/495x880.png', ...];
$.myPlugin({
    slides: $.map(imageArray, function (el) { return {image: el}; });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should convert it...

```
var imageArray = ['images/1000x800.png','images/495x880.png','images/600x800.png'];

for(var i=0; i<imageArray.length; i++) {
   imageArray[i] = {'image': imageArray[i]};
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/vxk4D/).

Though note, this will convert the original array. If you want a second one for this, simply make a new one with `var new = []` and `new.push()` the object inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just define the array you need instead of defining one and converting?

```
var imageArray = [
                    { image: 'images/1000x800.png' },
                    { image: 'images/495x880.png' },
                    { image: 'images/600x800.png' }
                 ];

jQuery(function($) {
    $.myplugin( { slides: imageArray } );
});
```